# Operator overloading outside of a class in a namespace

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload the comparison operator for a union class in a namespace to use it as a key in an unordered_map.

x.h:

```
#include <DirectXPackedVector.h>

namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<DirectX::PackedVector::XMUBYTEN4>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(DirectX::PackedVector::XMUBYTEN4 const& s) const {
            std::size_t const h1(std::hash<uint8_t>()(s.x));
            std::size_t const h2(std::hash<uint8_t>()(s.y));
            std::size_t const h3(std::hash<uint8_t>()(s.z));
            std::size_t const h4(std::hash<uint8_t>()(s.w));
            return h1 ^ (h2 << 1) ^ (h3 << 2) ^ (h4 << 3);
        }
    };
}

    std::unordered_map<DirectX::PackedVector::XMUBYTEN4, unsigned int> mc_province_index;
```

The hashing works fine but when i try to overload the comparison operator like so:

```
bool operator==(const DirectX::PackedVector::XMUBYTEN4 & lhs, const DirectX::PackedVector::XMUBYTEN4 & rhs) {
    if (lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y && lhs.z == rhs.z && lhs.w == rhs.w)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I get a

```
C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const DirectX::PackedVector::XMUBYTEN4' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I tried doing it inside the namespace

```
namespace DirectX{
    namespace PackedVector{
        bool operator==(const DirectX::PackedVector::XMUBYTEN4 & lhs, const DirectX::PackedVector::XMUBYTEN4 & rhs) {
            if (lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y && lhs.z == rhs.z && lhs.w == rhs.w)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but this gives me a LNK2005 saying it is already defined in object file.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I overload this operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define your `operator==()` as `inline` function if present in header file because you are very probably going to violate One Definition Rule.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition [One Definition Rule]

> One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable
>   that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire
>   program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). The
>   compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior
>   of the program that violates it is undefined.
>
> For an inline function,
>   a definition is required in every translation unit where it is
>   odr-used.

Basically there are bug categories how to violate ODR.

1. Multiple definitions in single compilation unit. That's why we are using include guards in header files.
2. No violation on compilation unit level but multiple compilation units containing the definition  that are linked together. (This case.)

Fix is trivial:

```
namespace DirectX{
    namespace PackedVector{
        inline bool operator==(const DirectX::PackedVector::XMUBYTEN4 & lhs, const DirectX::PackedVector::XMUBYTEN4 & rhs) {
            if (lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y && lhs.z == rhs.z && lhs.w == rhs.w)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding inline works, but i'm not fully understanding why. This is the only place I have defined this function, why does it violate the one definition rule?

Comment: @rm Are you sure you are not including the file to different compilation units and linking those together later?

Comment: You're right, that's where the violation is occurring. Thanks